# How to get a custom event from `wrapper.emitted` function with vitest

Tags: testing, vuejs3, vite, vitest

I use vitest on Vue3 (script setup TS) & and when a I want to trigger a custom event from my button, nothing appear with function `wrapper.emitted()`.

**button.spec.ts**

```
  it("should emit an event when button is clicked", async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(InfoCard, {
      props: {
        title: "Title",
        description: "Description",
        buttonText: "Button text",
      },
    });

    wrapper.vm.$emit("onEventFired");
    await wrapper.find("button").trigger("click");

    expect(wrapper.emitted("onEventFired")).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

**button.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { PropType } from "vue";

defineProps({
  buttonText: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: "onEventFired"): void;
}>();
</script>

<template>
   <button class="mb-3" @click="emit('onEventFired')">
      {{ buttonText }}
   </button>
</template>
```

Here I define my events and try to fire in on my test but nothing appears with wrapper.emitted

Does someone have an idea or solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Example from the doc https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/emitted.html

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

test('emit demo', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Component)

  wrapper.vm.$emit('foo')
  wrapper.vm.$emit('foo', 123)

  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick() // Wait until $emits have been handled

  /*
  wrapper.emitted() returns the following object:
  {
    foo: [[], [123]]
  }
  */

  // assert event has been emitted
  expect(wrapper.emitted().foo).toBeTruthy()

  // assert event count
  expect(wrapper.emitted().foo.length).toBe(2)

  // assert event payload
  expect(wrapper.emitted().foo[1]).toEqual([123])
})
```

Try to delete wrapper.vm.$emit("onEventFired");
Add   await wrapper.vm.$nextTick() // Wait until $emits have been handled

and check - expect(wrapper.emitted().onEventFired).toBeTruthy();